# Referencing Surrogate keys

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have 2 tables Customers & Accounts in my Oracle Database. I have sequence numbers for generating surrogate key values for both tables.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE         customers_seq   NOCACHE;
CREATE SEQUENCE         accounts_seq    NOCACHE;


CREATE TABLE            customers
(
customer_surrogate_id   NUMBER(10),     
customer_id             VARCHAR2(8) UNIQUE      NOT NULL,
customer_password       VARCHAR2(20),
customer_name           VARCHAR2(20), 
customer_pan            VARCHAR2(10)    UNIQUE,
customer_email_id       VARCHAR2(20)    UNIQUE,
CONSTRAINT              customer_pk 
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_surrogate_id)
);

CREATE TABLE            accounts
(
accounts_surrogate_id   NUMBER(10),
account_id              VARCHAR2(10)    UNIQUE      NOT NULL,
customer_surrogate_id   NUMBER(10),
account_type            VARCHAR2(10),
account_currency        VARCHAR2(20),
account_balance         NUMBER(20, 2), 
CONSTRAINT              accounts_pk 
    PRIMARY KEY (accounts_surrogate_id), 
CONSTRAINT          accounts_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_surrogate_id) 
        REFERENCES  customers(customer_surrogate_id)
);
```

I know how to use `sequence_name.NEXTVAL` & `sequence_name.CURRVAL` in insert statements to perform the reference

The problem is with using `NEXTVAL` & `CURRVAL` is that it assumes that inserts to both tables occur sequentially like

```
insert into Customers(// use NEXTVAL here)
insert into Accounts(// use CURRVAL here to reference the above row in Customers)
```

But in my java application, the multiple inserts for the Customers table can occur before even one insert occurs in Accounts table. `CURRVAL` will return the value of the last inserted row of the Customers table.

When inserting a row into Accounts table, I can get customers_id values in my application. Should the `customer_id` be used to query the Customers table to get the `customer_surrogate_id` as shown below?

```
insert into Customers(// use NEXTVAL here)
...
insert into Accounts(// use the customer_id to query and find customer_surrogate_id)
```

Is there better way to reference the Customers table in this situation?

Edit: I am using JDBC to access the database.

Comment: Do you use plain old JDBC or JPA / Hibernate? They would be helpful in this situation. Pleae show us your java code how you insert data

Comment: Do you have a Customer object that can store the generated ID as soon as the record is inserted? Without showing any code there is no indication of where the data you are inserting is coming from, or if you're keeping it (or just working through a file, say, and not retaining anything).

Answer (score 0):

Simply select the value, and store it in a variable:

```
long customer1Id = selectNextValueFromSequence("customers_seq");
long customer2Id = selectNextValueFromSequence("customers_seq");

insertCustomerWithId(customer1Id);
insertCustomerWithId(customer2Id);

insertAccountWithCustomerId(customer1Id);
insertAccountWithCustomerId(customer2Id);
```